# Using and displaying data using shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a .mat file that contains certain data. How would I insert that data and be able to display it using Shiny?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `R.matlab` package and the `readMat()` function to get the file into R, after that, you can build a shiny app from scratch the way you normally would.